# How to account for different trial durations in mixed models?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, biostatistics, beta-regression, glmmtmb

My experiment was conducted in multiple years. Each year, plants were sown in an infested field and then harvested after a certain time. There was a weather station to record weather data. I would like to use mixed models to investigate the effect of weather variables on disease development. The problem is the duration of experiment varied each year. Plants exposed to different weather conditions for varying period likely affected disease severity. Is there a way to account for different trial durations in GLMMs? Would it help if I include total number of days in each year as an offset term `offset(log(total_days))`? If I use an offset, would that mean that infection was proportional to the total number of days in each, and thus solve the problem?
My response variable is disease severity per plot. There were 10 plants per plot. Disease severity for each plot was recorded by adding the percentage of leaf area infected. I have divided the percentage by 100 to  get proportions for fitting bet regression. My response variable is positive with value ranges between 0 , 1 (both exclusive). There a total of 11 years as shown in the table below, but there are a total of 37 data points, so the data is not very large.

[image]

I am thinking to fit something like this.

```r
mod <- glmmTMB (disease_severity ~ mean_rh + mean_temp + 
                 mean_wind_speed + total_rain + (1|year) +  
                 offset(log(total_days)), 
                 family = beta_family(),  data = dat)
```

Comment: How was disease severity measured? Was it something similar to the fraction of plants that were diseased upon harvest? Also, for how man years do you have data? The answer could depend on those details. Pleas provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM Thanks for the comment. Severity was measured something similar to what you mentioned, it was the percentage of leaf area/plant infected. I divided the response variable by 100 to convert data from percentage to proportions to use beta family. Years information is in the Table. There were two different trial in 2015, so they were named as 2015_a & 2015_b. Based on readings, offset won't do the job to the logit link function. Including total days as a covariate is one option. I have edited the question with the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any use of `total_days` or a simple transformation like its logarithm is making a particular assumption about the association of `disease_severity` with `total_days`. That's going to be tricky in your situation, as many of your `disease_severity` values are already close to the maximum value of 1. Simple assumptions are unlikely to work.

The approach most likely to account for differences in the number of `total_days` is to model `disease_severity` as a flexible function of `total_days`, for example with regression splines, so that the data can tell you the form of the association. The difficulty is that you have a very restricted data set of 37 data points, while you are already trying to fit 4 fixed-effect predictors and a random effect for `year`. Thus you are in danger of overfitting your data.

Frank Harrell's [online notes](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) provide guidance on how to use your knowledge of the subject matter to match your model to the available data. You might also consider a generalized additive model. See, for example, the R [`mgcv` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mgcv). That can allow flexible modeling of all of your continuous predictors while penalizing coefficients to minimize overfitting.